# Printing BST keys in the given range

Tags: algorithm, runtime

I am trying to understand the runtime of printing BST keys in the given range. 
I tried to understand it from [this example](http://prpds.blogspot.com/2011/07/print-bst-keys-in-given-range.html), but I could not.

I think I understand where the `O(log n)` is coming from. That is from going through the BST recursively, this will take `O(log n)` for each side, but I am not sure about:

1. Where the `K` is coming from. is it just the constant time it takes to print? if yes why is the runtime not `O(log n)` + `O(k)` , and than you would ignore the K
2. Where is the `O(n)` from the in order traversal? because it is not in this runtime.
3. How the runtime will change if we have several values in the range on each side of the tree. For example, what if the range was from 4?

Comment: K is the number of items printed.  No matter how fast you can find the beginning and end, you have to print all the items.  The more items you have to print, the longer it will take.

Comment: usefully when you have a constant you say `O(some value)` + `O(c)` and ignore the c because it is asymptotically smaller. why are we adding this into our `O(log)` in this case?

Comment: K is not a constant.  It varies based on the inputs.

Comment: Thank you. I understand part a of my question now :)

Comment: That page has two implementations.  Only the second one has complexity `O(log n) + O(k)`, because it does a better job of ignoring the parts of the tree that can't contribute to the output.

Comment: will you be able to explain why? Mostly I am confused about the in order traversal , because this should take `O(n)`

Comment: The second version isn't doing a full in-order traversal.  It skips the branches that are clearly not relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easier way to understand the solution is to consider the following algorithm:

1. Searching for a minimum value greater than key k1 in the BST tree - O(lgn)
2. Performing in-order traversal of the BST tree nodes from k1 till we reach a node less than or equal to k2, and printing their keys. Because the in-order traversal of the complete BST takes O(n) time, if there are k keys between k1 and k2, the in-order traversal will take O(k) time.

The given algorithm is doing the same thing; Searching for a key between k1 and k2 takes O(lgn) time, whereas printing is done only for k keys within the range k1 and k2 which is O(k). If all BST keys lie within k1 and k2, the runtime will be O(lgn) + O(n) = O(n) because all n keys need to be printed out.